# I need to check if my mouse is inside the window to blit a custom cursor

Tags: python

As i said I'm trying to check if my mouse is inside the window to blit an external cursor that i downloaded as a png, because when the mouse leaves the window the cursor image will freeze at the last place my mouse was in before leaving the window.

here is my code inside the game loop:

```
 x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
 if x > 0 and x < MAX_X and y > 0 and y < MAX_Y:
    screen.blit(cursor, cursorRect)
```

and before the loop:

```
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1316,740))    
MAX_X, MAX_Y = screen.get_size()
```

The problem is that the code works for the upper part and left part of the window but it doesnt affect the right and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it while typing the question by checking if the x and the y are smaller than the window size **- 1**

thought i'd leave it here to spare any newbies like me 30 minutes of their time:

```
if x > 0 and x < MAX_X - 1 and y > 0 and y < MAX_Y - 1:
    screen.blit(cursor, cursorRect)
```